# Camera is opening but some time it crashing on click image ok button in android some device like Redmi 7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I given all the permission in manifest. Every thing working fine but after taking picture on click ok button is crashing.  Please help me any solution
This message showing

```
    E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
    E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.app.mytestapp
        getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    W/s.mytestapp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    W/s.mytestapp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    W/s.mytestapp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
        Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

Using this code open camera

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + StrFolderName + "/" , filename + ".jpg"));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            FileProcessing obj = new FileProcessing(FinalActivty.this);

            File f = new File(uri.getPath());
            Double capturedSize= Double.valueOf((float) f.length() / (1024));
            String Originalsize = String.format("%.5f", capturedSize);
            Double actualPhoto = Double.parseDouble(Originalsize);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the error messages?

Comment: Yes. Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict". Why it is happening don't know. tried lot. Do you have any solution?

Comment: No, I don't.  But I put your error message into Stack Overflow's search box and pressed Enter.  And, well, you're not gonna believe this, but you're not actually the first person to encounter this problem!  Why don't you [try doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access+denied+finding+property) yourself.

Comment: Okay. I will try

Comment: Given all the permission. but not able to find specific solution for this

Answer (score 1):

just add the below line in your manifest application tag attribute.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

but this is a temporary solution. from **android r** requestLegacyExternalStorage will deprecated.
for more details, you can refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

**OR**

just replace your file path, you can try the below code

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURE) + "/" + StrFolderName + "/" , filename + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: Commented Uri will work for all versions of android?

Comment: I do not conform to below marshmallow version. But I have tested on marshmallow and above versions its working fine.